# display charts using java scripts in android

Tags: javascript, android

I need to display line chart, bar chart and candle chart in android.

For that I am using jqPlot charts.

I am passing string values from java code to javascript function.

In candle chart the script accepting values in 2D array only.

How can I covert string to 2D array in java script.
my code is as follows.

In java code.

```
String myValue = "'06/15/2009 16:00:00', 136.01, 139.5, 134.53, 139.48_"+ "'06/15/2009 16:00:00', 136.01, 139.5, 134.53, 139.48";
webView.loadUrl("javascript:showCandleChart(" + myValue+ ")");
```

java script accept values in this format

```
ohlc = [
    ['06/15/2009 16:00:00', 136.01, 139.5, 134.53, 139.48],
    ['06/08/2009 16:00:00', 143.82, 144.56, 136.04, 136.97],
    ['06/01/2009 16:00:00', 136.47, 146.4, 136, 144.67],
    ['05/26/2009 16:00:00', 124.76, 135.9, 124.55, 135.81],
    ['05/18/2009 16:00:00', 123.73, 129.31, 121.57, 122.5],
    ['05/11/2009 16:00:00', 127.37, 130.96, 119.38, 122.42],
    ['05/04/2009 16:00:00', 128.24, 133.5, 126.26, 129.19],
    ['04/27/2009 16:00:00', 122.9, 127.95, 122.66, 127.24],
    ['04/20/2009 16:00:00', 121.73, 127.2, 118.6, 123.9]]
```

My java script function

```
function showCandleChart(ohlc) {
// here ohlc string need to convert to 2D array as shown in above format.
var plot2 = $
    .jqplot(
            'chart2',
            [ ohlc ],
            {
                seriesDefaults : {
                    yaxis : 'y2axis'
                },
                axes : {
                    xaxis : {
                        renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        tickOptions : {
                            formatString : '%b %e'
                        },
                        min : "09-01-2008",
                        max : "06-22-2009",
                        tickInterval : "6 weeks"
                    },
                    y2axis : {
                        tickOptions : {
                            formatString : '$%d'
                        }
                    }
                },
                // To make a candle stick chart, set the "candleStick" option to true.
                series : [ {
                    renderer : $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer,
                    rendererOptions : {
                        candleStick : true
                    }
                } ],
                highlighter : {
                    show : true,
                    showMarker : false,
                    tooltipAxes : 'xy',
                    yvalues : 4,
                    formatString : 

'<table class="jqplot-highlighter"> \
  <tr><td>date:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>open:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>hi:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>low:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>close:</td><td>%s</td></tr></table>'
                    }
                });

}
```

Please help..
I should get output like this.
[image]

Comment: if you are going to call from Java code why do not you use Gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) whereby you you can send the string in JSON format from your java code and when you get it in javascript code you can parse it.

Comment: Even if I get JSON I need to convert it to 2D array. can you give an example about what you say.

Comment: see suppose you have a variable in java in holding value  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] the JSON string would be "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]" using Gson and on client side when you get this you can just parse it By using JSON.parse to get your 2D array back

Comment: Actually I am new to java and java script. I did not get what you are saying. can you please give a sample code to track it out.

Comment: see an example is on this link (http://www.javaiq.net/javacoderanch/how-to-convert-array-into-json.html) now when you get the JSON string say [1,1,2,3,5,8,13] then in javascript you can do        var s = "[1,1,2,3,5,8,13]";  This will also work for nested array as in your case
var d = JSON.parse(s);
here d will hold 2D array like this
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

Comment: I have made these steps
String[][] linesCsv = {{ "06/15/2009 16:00:00", "136.01", "139.5", "134.53", "139.48" },{ "06/15/2009 16:00:00", "136.01", "139.5", "134.53", "139.48" }};
String array = gson.toJson(linesCsv);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:showCandleChart(" + array + ")");
Now how can I use this array in javaScript.?

Comment: now the string array pass it in your function and in javascript when you get it try to save it in variable s = JSON.parse(your string) ans see what s holds in console; what still concern me here is its array of string while you have to pass float values in array but first see are you getting values.

Answer (score 0):

RGraph uses the HTML5 Canvas component, which is NOT accommodated in the webkit packaged with Android 1.5. RGraph works nicely & tested with Android 2.1 and 2.2.

Example of the HTML/Javascript approach:

Calendar using Epoch
3D-Rotating cube uses HTML/Javascript